# when app is in background setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler doesnot print the notification title in console notification is send in onesignal

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler((OSNotificationReceivedEvent event) {
event.complete(event.notification);
print('notification title ${event.notification.title}');
});``

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in onesignal notification i have received foreground notification but i want to print notification on console(log) so that i can know the title of the notification and provide custom sound to particular notification.

Comment: `setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler ` name itself suggests it will work in Foreground only.  YOu will need to write your own service extension for what you want. More details here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions